# Google Sign-in not working in an Cordova App

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, web, google-signin

So I created a sign-in (with Google) page with the help of this guide: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button.

- It works just fine in any browser but not in my Cordova App.
- Normally it should open a new window if I click on the "Sign-in with Google" button, but in the Cordova App there's **no new window popping up**.

---

**My short term solution:**

For now I am just opening my sign-in page in an Inappbrowser (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html) to have it work, but I don't think this is a nice way to solve this problem.

Appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a cordova library made already for that have a look on [this](https://github.com/cabotdeveloper/CordovaPlugin-GooglePlusLogin) Github repo

Comment: why is inappbrowser not a nice way to do it? If it works OK then I would of thought it would be fine

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer another Cordova library over the library which is mentioned in the accepted answer. [Eddy Verbruggen's](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen) "[cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)" plugin/library has a really **great documentation** and **way more features**.

---

**One of the reasons I chose Eddy Verbruggen's plugin/library:**

While a Google login with the [library of the accepted answer](https://github.com/cabotdeveloper/CordovaPlugin-GooglePlusLogin) returns the following JSON object (if the login was successful),

```
obj.Name    // "Tester"
obj.Email   // "tester@testing.com"
obj.Gender  // "1"
```

Eddy Verbruggens plugin/library returns the following object which has way more information:

```
obj.email          // "eddyverbruggen@gmail.com"
obj.userId         // user id
obj.displayName    // "Eddy Verbruggen"
obj.familyName     // "Verbruggen"
obj.givenName      // "Eddy"
obj.imageUrl       // "http://link-to-my-profilepic.google.com"
obj.idToken        // idToken that can be exchanged to verify user identity.
obj.serverAuthCode // Auth code that can be exchanged for an access token and refresh token for offline access
obj.accessToken    // OAuth2 access token
```

Other awesome features/differences can be seen on the GitHub repository of the plugin/library.